# Show that there is a ring isomorphism from $\Bbb Z_2$ to a subring of $\Bbb Z_{2n}$ if and only if $n$ is odd.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $n\in \Bbb N$.
>   Show that there is a ring isomorphism   from $\Bbb Z_2$ to a subring of $\Bbb Z_{2n}$ if and only if $n$ is odd.

Let $\phi:\Bbb Z_2\to \Bbb Z_{2n}$ be a ring isomorphism.

Then $2\mid  2n$. So $n$ can be both odd or even.

How to show that $n$ is odd from here?

Conversely : Define $\phi :\Bbb Z_2\to \Bbb Z_{2n}$ by $\phi(0)=0;\phi(1)=1$

Then $\phi$ is a ring-isomorphism from $\Bbb Z_2$ to  $\{0,1\}$ which is a subring of $\Bbb Z_{2n}$

Comment: Th function $\phi$ you gave is not a homomorphism, becuase $\phi(1)+\phi(1)\neq\phi(1+1)=\phi(0)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is a subring of $Z_{2n}$ such that $R$ is isomorphic to $Z_2$.

Let $f:Z_2 \to R$ be an isomorphism, and let $x = f(1)$.

Then $R = \{0,x\}$, for some $x \in Z_{2n}$, with $x \ne 0$.

Since $1+1 = 0$ in $Z_2$, it follows that $x+x=0$ in $R$, hence also $x+x = 0$ in $Z_{2n}$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&x + x = 0\;\text{in}\;Z_{2n}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2x \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;2n)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;n)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x = n\qquad\text{[since $x \in \{0,...,2n-1\},\;$and$\;x \ne 0$]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Since $1^2 = 1$ in $Z_2$, it follows that $n^2 = n$ in $R$, hence also $n^2 = n$ in $Z_{2n}$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&n^2 = n\;\text{in}\;Z_{2n}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&n^2 \equiv n\;(\text{mod}\;2n)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&n \equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;2)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Hence $n$ is odd.

Conversely, if $n$ is odd, let $R$ be the subset of $Z_{2n}$ given by $R = \{0,n\}$.

To finish, verify:

1. $\;R$ is a subring of $Z_{2n}$.$\\[8pt]$

   $\;$The map $f:Z_2 \to R$ defined by
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   f(0) = 0
   \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
   \\
   f(1) = n
   \end{cases}
   $$
   is an isomorphism.

Comment: Great Work +1 Thanks